# Is it considered bad to put the <title> tag outside the <head> tag?

Tags: html, title, head

Is it considered bad to put the `<title>` tag outside the `<head>` tag? I'm using PHP and I only know the page name after loading the header.php file where `<head>` is located. Would placing the `<title>` tag later in the page influence SEO or cause any other browser related problems or would you advice against it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes the [`title` tag should only be used in the `head`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110705/the-title-element.html).

So I'm guessing your `header.php` has a line like this:

```
<title><?php echo $title ?></title>
```

And on your pages you have an `include('pathtofile/header.php');`
Just define `$title` before the include line.

Example:

```
$title = "This is my page title";
include("includes/header.php");
```

Or if it isn't structured like that you may want to change it up a bit.

Comment: sadly, no the header is actually loaded before the page. `include "header.php"; include "page.php"`  It's not my own site and it's a lot of work to change the structure.

Comment: @inControl You could use javascript to change it after the page is loaded? I know that probably won't help an SEO effort...

Comment: I geuss ill just have too change the structure, I was worried i woul've but I just wanted to make sure there was no other 'correct' way.

Answer (score 1):

The [`title`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-title-element) is part of the metadata of the document, so yes, it would be semantically incorrect to put it outside the `head`:

> #### [4.2.2 The title element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-title-element)
>
> **Contexts in which this element can be used:**
>   In a [`head`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-head-element) element containing no other [`title`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-title-element) elements.